# PowerShell waiting for Enter Key

Tags: powershell

I'm having some trouble with PowerShell waiting for Enter key before continuing script. I have whole script written, but I've managed to isolate one of the cases where I have to press enter key for command to continue or exit:

I have this command

```
$varvalue=(C:\Temp\MyConsoleApp.exe -nsd "paramvalue") | Out-String
```

`MyConsoleApp.exe` is just some console application that returns some string. If I execute this PS command, the cursor positions itself in the next line and it waits. If I press Enter key, command terminates and I get back to shell (MyConsoleApp finished quickly, so it's actually not executing that long). If I check `$varvalue`, it has correct value, just this Enter press is bugging me.

Why is PS waiting for Enter key? Is there something I'm missing? Are there any global settings about that? I'm also not clicking with a mouse (I've read that sometimes QuickEdit mode might be the problem, when selection begins; that is not the case here).

Comment: Possibly just a common issue where you click your mouse in there and it stops showing the output until you press enter.

Comment: what happens when you execute `$varvalue = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Temp\MyConsoleApp.exe' -ArgumentList '-nsd "paramvalue"' -Wait`?

Comment: @DougMaurer: there is no mouse clicking involved. After I execute command, I wait for some time and then hit enter and only then the command ends (mouse is not touched in this time).

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz: If I try that, it opens up CMD window with a result string written in it and I still have to hit enter to close it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Turns out if exception occurs (as it did in some cases), this console app had Console.ReadLine() in it.